# How to implement cumulative score in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Can someone explain me what is "cumulative score" and how to implement it on `Matlab`?

I searched on the net and i found out that the cumulative score is defined as the percentage of test images such that the absolute error is not higher than the threshold `t`, (in years in this study). 
I read in an article that the cumulative score is calculated as shown in the image.

[image: Cumulative Score]

I also used the "one category error" in my study, calculated as following:

```
correct = abs(predict_label - test_label) <= 1;
num_correct = length(find(correct));
accuracy2Svmk2 = (num_correct ./ length(test_label)) * 100;
```

these two metrics can be the same more or less?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the "1-":

```
accuracy2Svmk2 = (1 - (num_correct ./ length(test_label))) * 100;
```

Comment: no, that's not the problem..The "one category error" script is correct. I though that cumulative score and "one category error" were the same thing but i was wrong. I don't understand what is cumulative score and i can't find anything useful on the net.. i read different articles that use this metric but i still don't understand. Thank you anyway.